# Angular Bootstrap switching tabs and passing data using data-toggle

Tags: angular, tabs

I'm fairly new to Angular and need to solve seems to be simple problem: pass the data between tabs in angular bootstrap based project.

Currently I have main component that has tab structure (will try to simplify things):

```
<div>  
  <div>
      <ul id="tab1">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            [ngClass]="{'nav-link': true, 'active': (activeTab === 'tab-1')}"
            data-toggle="tab"
            href="#tab1" (click)="activeTab = 'tab-1'">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            [ngClass]="{'nav-link': true, 'active': (activeTab === 'tab-2')}"
            data-toggle="tab"
            href="#tab2" role="tab" (click)="activeTab = 'tab-2'">Tab2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

    <div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade {{activeTab === 'tab-1' ? 'show active' : ''}}" id="tab1-tab" #tab1
           role="tabpanel">
        <app-tab1 [id]="id"></app-tab1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade {{activeTab === 'tab-2' ? 'show active' : ''}}" id="tab2-tab" #tab2
           role="tabpanel">
        <app-tab2 [id]="id"></app-tab2>
      </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Each tab is represented by its own component. Switching between tabs works fine. First tab is an overview of items represented as a table (p-dataTable), in the second tab you can choose one of the item and get some details about it (functionality is already represented).
The behavior I'm trying to implement is: "Click the item in the table in the first tab -> Tab is switched to the second tab and this item is selected in the dropdown and item info is displayed".

The issue I've encountered is that tabs structure is one component, first tab is in another and the second one is in a separate one. So when in the first tab there is no notion of other tabs and no way to pass the id of the item.
We are using routing to switch between different components, but in this case the path shouldn't be changed since those all components representing tabs under the same path, let's say /items

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it via using BehaviorSubject and passing the data and active tab value between components.